# Why is a solution of an ODE that is non zero at point non zero everywhere? Stewarts Calculus book

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading the chapter about differential equations in Stewarts Calculus, Concepts and Context 4th edition. On page 510 it says that if a solution $y(x)\neq 0$ for some x then, by some uniqueness theorem, $y(x)\neq 0$ for all x.

Since there is no reference to any specific function I get the impression that this statement is true in general. But that's not the case, isn't it?
(This has already been pointed out it the comments via counter examples.)

Furthermore there is the claim that $y(x)\neq0$ for all "x". Does this mean "for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$? All I know is that $y(x)\neq 0$ in a neighbourhood of x, since $y(x)$ is continuous, since it is differentiable . $y(x)$ is a solution, hence it is differentiable. Is there some extension theorem I am not considering with which y(x) can be extended to all of $\mathbb{R}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am downvoting this question because it is not self contained.

Comment: @5xum Unfortunately the book doesn't give more information either. That's all there is.

Comment: @Hans If we take the differential equation $y' = 1$ and the initial condition $y(-1)=-1$, then clearly, $y(x)=x$ is the only solution, and this function does not satisfy the condition that you describe. So, either (1) the book is wrong (unlikely), (2) you are missing some details or (3) there is implicit details in the book you are not sharing. I can't judge, because I don't have the book - which is exactly what I mean when I say this question is not self contained.

Comment: @5xum okay makes sense. :) found the book on google books by using stewart calculus differential equations

Comment: I get a preview of the book on google books. And even if I had it at home, that wouldn't make this question any more self-contained...

Comment: @5xum Then I don’t see how I can make it more self-contained...

Comment: @Hans: You'll need to tell us **which differential equation** the book is talking about in this context (since clearly the statement isn't true for all differential equations).

Comment: And it would also help to say **which edition** of the book that you're using, since "page 510" need not be the same in different editions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look back in your text, you will most likely find that the function $y(x)=0$ is a solution, that is, in $y'=f(x,y)$ you have $f(x,0)=0$. Then the uniqueness theorem (the uniqueness claim of the Picard-Lindelöf theorem) indeed ensures that no other solution can take the value $0$ anywhere.

It seems as that book does not contain the deeper theorems nor any proofs. The most practical version of the uniqueness theorem is that if $f(x,y)$ is continuously differentiable in its domain, then any solution $y$ (with graph inside that domain) is unique.

Comment: The statement I am talking about is just an annotation that is right next to an example, which is $y'=y x^2$. Therefore $y=0$ is a solution I guess. So I suppose  that in the statement the function $y(x)$ is a meant to be a solution of the ODE  $y'=y x^2$?

Comment: Yes. As you see, in $f(x,y)=x^2y$ you have $f(x,0)=0$ for all $x$. You can also solve this problem using an integrating factor of $\exp(-x^3/3)$ where no division by zero is necessary. So the problem avoided here is not a problem of the equation, but of the solution method used.

Comment: Btw., that this equation and the method of separation of variables was discussed is necessary context that you should add to the question text.